# Is there a Standard Format for Clean URLs for Archives of Custom Posts?

Tags: posts, customization, urls

Are there standard formats for clean URL's for the various types of archives one would want from a collection of custom posts?

If, for instance, the slug for the custom post is "business":

```
Author: http://mysite.com/business/author/fred
Category: http://mysite.com/business/category/grocery
Tag: http://mysite.com/business/tag/employeeowned
Date: http://mysite.com/business/2014/08/
```

I am interested in these and other even more complex clean URL's.  Is there an authoritative reference or list of standards for different clean url's to use?

Comment: I am not sure what "standard" would be. URLs are generally set up for requirements of specific site, not to mention CPTs can be drastically different.

Comment: I think the examples I gave above are fairly standard even though they are for a CPT.  For the author example, the type of CPT would hardly matter.  Same with the other examples. I imagine that when people put together a business directory using wordpress there are various standard ways they archive by geography etc.